# Rendering international dates in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: date, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following `XAML` code:

```
<Label Text="{Binding startTime, StringFormat='{0:MMM d, yyyy }'}" />
```

which renders **June 18, 2017**

I'd like to create a string that renders **18 June 2017** when the culture is not US.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`MMM` will give you an abbreviated month name, you have to use the `MMMM` if you want to get the full month name. More from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Your *XAML* code should look:

`<Label Text="{Binding CurrentDate, StringFormat='{0:d MMMM yyyy}'}}" />`